# Call a function at runtime depending on user input?

Tags: .net

Is it possible in .net, call a function at run time depending on  'user' input ?

Suppose i've a function called

```
private void MyFunction1() {
 }

private void MyFunction2(String arg1, Double arg2) {

 }
```

If a user write "MyFunction1" in a text box ...the program will execute that function. 
If yes, it works also with MyFunction2 with parameter passed by user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Reflection.MethodInfo info = Type.GetType("ClassName").GetMethod("MethodName");

In your case, "MethodName" would come from the user input.
Once you have your MethodInfo object, you call call Invoke on it.